# MySQL - Group By SUM with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I'm using MySQL 5.1 and I have two tables, projects and employee. There is a foreign key in employee (number_project) that is the primary key of projects(code_project).

---> Exactly: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f54cd/3/0)

I'm trying get the SUM of the projects by department with this query:

```
SELECT emp.department_emp AS Department, SUM( pro.price ) AS total_department
FROM employee AS emp, projects AS pro
WHERE emp.number_project = pro.code_project
GROUP BY emp.department_emp
```

It returns:

```
DEPARTMENT  TOTAL_DEPARTMENTA
Accounting   2600
IT           4200
```

But It should returns:

```
DEPARTMENT  TOTAL_DEPARTMENT
Accounting   1300
IT           4200
```

The problem is that when the query sums the same projects many times as employees of the same department are working in that project.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you do if two employees from different departments work on the same project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to create a list of unique `(department, project)` combinations:

```
select  e.department_emp
,       sum(p.price)
from    (
        select  distinct department_emp
        ,       number_project
        from    Employee
        ) e
join    Projects p
on      p.code_project = e.number_project
group by
        e.department_emp
```

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f54cd/8/0)

Your database could use some serious work.  Employee to project should be a many-to-many relation, not a many-to-one relation.  And a field called "number" should not be called "code" in another table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that the database it's not good. I just trying make some practices

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery that "collapses" the employees, arbitrarily choosing the department of one employee from the project:

```
SELECT department,
       SUM(price) AS total_department
  FROM ( SELECT project.code_project AS project,
                project.price AS price,
                MIN(employee.department_emp) AS department
          FROM project
          JOIN employee
            ON project.code_project = employee.number_project
         GROUP
            BY project.code_project,
               project.price
       )
 GROUP
    BY department
;
```

(Naturally, this will give misleading results if a single project has employees from multiple different departments, because it will assign the entire price of the project to one of those departments.)

Comment: As you say at the end, this answer makes no sense at all.  Why post it?

Comment: @Andomar . . . Your solution returns the wrong results if employees on a project could be in multiple departments.  Your criticism seems unfair.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Arbitrarily assigning a project to a department (or rather, the first alphabetical department) makes no sense-- unless you work for "_AAccounting", I guess.  You make a good point about double-counting projects, but that would be normal in a "how much CAPEX is this department involved in" type query.

Comment: @Andomar . . . Multiple employees on a project.  Each employee in their own department.  That is the problem (for both approaches).  (If may not be relevant to the OPs situation if this cannot occur, for some reason.)

Comment: @Andomar: Your answer also "makes no sense at all": it gives misleading results in the same circumstance. And yet, you posted it . . .

Answer (score 0):

SELECT emp.department_emp AS Department, SUM( pro.price ) AS total_department
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM employee AS emp, projects AS pro
WHERE emp.number_project = pro.code_project
) AS P
GROUP BY emp.department_emp